# How to add an image to MimeMessageHelper as inline image from a byte array?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to add an inline image to the email, so I am using spring boot and their JavaMailSender mechanism.

Now it results in a NPE when I try to add an image via the addInline method

```
 byte[] attachmentData = aMailConfig.getAttachments().get(messageAttach).getBinaryData();
 LOG.debug("size of attachment is {0}", attachmentData.length);
 Resource res = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(attachmentData));
 msg.addInline(messageAttach, res);
```

Here the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(MimetypesFileTypeMap.java:299)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.getContentType(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:184)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addInline(MimeMessageHelper.java:941)
```

The problem is, that there is call to the resource.getFilename() in the addInline method.
As I am generating the Resource with InputStreamResource, there is no filename set. Is there a way so that I can set this filename in my case or is it necessary to create a tempfile and generate the resource object by using this file?

Here the addLine mehod of the org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper

```
  public void addInline(String contentId, Resource resource) throws MessagingException {
    Assert.notNull(resource, "Resource must not be null");
    String contentType = getFileTypeMap().getContentType(resource.getFilename());
    addInline(contentId, resource, contentType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward:

```java
Resource res = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(attachmentData)) {
  @Override
  public String getFilename() {
    return "dummy-filename.io"; // or something more complex/dynamic (but "file name like"!)
  }     
};
```

...(anonymous) override the "malicious method", with something that suits us better.

But BEST, we would know the MimeType of attachment (not guessing it from a fictive file name), use the "more appropriate not malicious method" (overload), and just set it like:

```
msg.addInline(
  "contentId",
  new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(attachmentData)), 
  "image/jpeg" // knowing it or guessing it.
);
```

[javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#addInline-java.lang.String-org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource-java.lang.String-).

So VERY BEST would be, when:

```
aMailConfig.getAttachments().get(messageAttach)
```

besides `getBinaryData():byte[]` also had a (correct) `getContentType():String` (..or even `get[Original]FileName():String` ;).